# GoLang based Web Server to upload / download AWS S3 objects

Tags: go, amazon-s3, webserver

This might be a very basic problem but I am looking for the best options / recommendations available today.

**Problem Statement**:
We have a web app which allow users to upload and download files (stored in S3). We also want server to authenticate the request first before starting the upload / download.

**Few options**:

1. Use S3 pre-signed URLs: I certainly want to avoid this because these are private files and anyone who gets access to the pre-signed URLS can access those. (We can't even afford to take risk by setting the expiration time of the pre-signed URL to few seconds)
2. Once authentication is done, stream data directly to/from S3 to client. Is this possible and viable? Do we have any tools or reference implementation for this?

This question might be a repeat of similar questions from the past (but they are very old), I wonder what all tools / options we have today to solve this?

I am mostly looking for options in GoLang / Python (GoLang is preferable). Happy to consider storage services other than S3 if that makes things easier (preference will be S3 though).

Comment: 2 is possible & viable. Recommendations for tools/reference implementations/tutorials are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Stream the data through your server by [copying](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy) the [object body](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3#GetObjectOutput.Body) to the [response](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter).

Comment: @BellinghamBoss IIUC, I need to download the S3 object on my server first then stream, right? What I am looking for is a web/proxy server which authenticates the user first and start the file download on the browser directly. Does that make sense? I am new to Go and AWS, so apologies if I am being stupid.

Comment: @ShivamJindal You can authenticate the user, issue the get object request, and stream the result down to the client from your server.  Use `io.Copy(responseWriter, getObjectOutput.Body)` to stream the data where `responseWriter` is the handler's response writer and `getObjectOutput` is the result of the get object call.   It is not necessary to download the S3 object first.